# Probability of winning in a table tennis game

Tags: probability

I'm working with the following problem:

> In table tennis, a set is won by the first player to reach 11 points, unless the
> score is $10–10$, in which case serves are alternated and the player who first
> gets ahead by two points wins. Suppose that Ann wins a point as server with
> probability $p_A$ and Bob wins a point as server with probability $p_B$. If the score
> is $10–10$ and Ann serves, what is the probability that she wins the set?

**Attempt:**

For our sake, let $P(W)$ be the probability of Ann winning, where $W$ is the event of winning. We also let $A$ be the event of Ann winning a serve and $B$ the event of bob winning a serve.

We draw ourselves a diagram of the situation:

[image]

Using the law of probability, we have:

$$P(W) = P(W|A)P(A) + P(W| A \cap A)P(A \cap A) + 2P(W| A \cap B)P(A \cap B) + P(W| B \cap B)P(B \cap B)$$

The last term vanishes, since the probability of Ann winning becomes $0$ if Bob wins $2$ serves in a row.

Furthermore, we realize that $P(W) = P(W|A \cap B) := p$. Hence, we have:

$$ p =  p_a^2 + 1 \cdot p_a^2 + 2p \cdot p_a \cdot p_b$$

Meaning we have $$ p = \frac{2p_a^2}{1-2p_a p_b}$$

but the answer sheet tells me that

$$ p = \frac{p_a(1-p_b)}{p_a+p_b-2p_a p_b}$$

I hope I can get some tips that'll help me solve this problem. I'm thinking that I get it wrong in the step where $P(W|A)P(A)$ is calculated, since it seems pretty off that this should be equal to the probability $P(W|A\cap A)P(A\cap A)$. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use $A$ and $\overline A$ for the possible results of first serve and $B$ and $\overline B$ for the second serve. It would make it a little easier to organize the different possible events. The fact that $A\cap A$ is different from $A$ looks a little strange. And if you just say $A$, does that event have probability $p_A$ or $1-p_B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the tip from my comment above, we have the events

- $A$: Ann wins the first serve (probability $p_A$)
- $B$: Bob wins the second serve (probability $p_B$)

We note that $A\cap B$ and $\overline A \cap \overline B$ both result in starting over. If the probability of winning is $p_W$, then we therefore have
$$
P(W\mid A\cap B)=p_W\\
P(W\mid \overline A\cap \overline B)=p_W
$$
The law of total probability yields
$$
\begin{align}
p_W={}&P(W\mid A\cap \overline B)P(A\cap\overline B)\\
&+P(W\mid A\cap B)P)A\cap B\\
&+P(W\mid\overline A\cap \overline B)P(\overline A\cap \overline B)\\
&+P(W\mid \overline A\cap B)P(\overline A\cap B)\\
={}&1\cdot p_A(1-p_B)+p_W\cdot p_Ap_B\\
&+p_W\cdot(1-p_A)(1-p_B)+0\cdot (1-p_A)(1-p_B)\\
={}&p_A(1-p_B)+p_W(p_Ap_B+(1-p_A)(1-p_B))
\end{align}
$$
Solving $p_W=p_A(1-p_B)+p_W(p_Ap_B+(1-p_A)(1-p_B))$ for $p_W$ does indeed yield
$$
p_W=\frac{p_A(1-p_B)}{1-(p_Ap_B+(1-p_A)(1-p_B))}\\
=\frac{p_A(1-p_B)}{p_A+p_B-2p_Ap_B}
$$

---

Alternately, the "Starting over" case may be simplified away using
$$
p_W=\frac{P(W\mid \text{not starting over})}{P(\text{not starting over})}\\
=\frac{p_A(1-p_B)}{p_A(1-p_B)+(1-p_A)p_B}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The probability of Ann winning any given deuce round (i.e., Ann serves a point, Bob serves a point) is given by $p_A\cdot(1-p_B)$ [Ann wins her service point, and then Bob loses his service point.]

Using your notation that $p$ is the probability of Ann winning the entire match from a score of $10$ - $10$, we have:

$p=p_A \cdot(1-p_B) + p\cdot [(p_A\cdot p_B)+(1-p_A)\cdot(1-p_B)]$

where $p_A\cdot (1-p_B)$ is the probability of Ann winning the first deuce round; and the bracketed term $[...]$ represents the probability of going to another deuce round (each player wins their service point; or each player loses their service point).

This should lead to the answer sheet's result quoted in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the notation, let $a,b$ be the respective probabilities  that $A,B$ win on their serve. We shall compute P(A wins)

Let $p$ be the probability that $A$ **ultimately** wins

Either $A$ wins in two points with probability $a(1-b)$ or is back to square one with probability $ab +(1-a)(1-b)$

Thus $p = a(1-b) + [ab+(1-a)(1-b)]p$ which simplifies to

$p = \dfrac{a(1-b)}{a+b-2ab}$